# Structure of JqueryMobile pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I am using Asp.net MVC to pull my pages when I require them.
The structure of my pages are:

```
{
   Layout = "";
}

  <div data-role="page"> 
     ....


      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).one("pageinit", function () {

          ....
      </script>

  </div>
```

Should I leave my page structures as above or should I put my scripts in one global external javascript file (in which case how would I do I associate each "pageinit" with the correct page)?

The other problem I am having is debugging the embedded script in chrome. Is this related to the fact it is embedded?

Answer (score 0):

If you move to a single JS include, which I suggest doing, then you will have an easier time maintaining the code as it will be in one place.

You could run `pageinit` code based on the ID of the pseudo-page that is being initialized:

```
//setup initialization code for each pseudo-page that needs it
var myCode = {
    someID : function (event) {
        //run initialization code for the pseudo-page with the ID of "someID"
    },
    someOtherID : function (event) {
        //run initialization code for the pseudo-page with the ID of "someOtherID"
    }
};

//setup a delegated event handler for each pseudo-page's "pageinit" event
$(document).on('pageinit', '.ui-page', function (event) {

    //check if a function for this pseudo-page exists
    if (this.id in myCode) {

        //since the function exists, call it and pass "this" as the current pseudo-page as well as passing-in the "event" object
        myCode[this.id].call(this, event);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done;

Firstly, I have all my scripts that I will ever need in one external JS file.

In my MVC layout page I have created the div for the data-role wrapper to set its id attribute from a property each and every controller action will return with a unique value.

The layout page.

```
<body class="ui-mobile-viewport">
    <div data-role="page" id="@ViewBag.PageId">
```

Then in my Controller Action I return a unique value to the view;

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
             ViewBag.PageId = "pageCustomers";

            return View();
        }
```

This means that I can bind to the page.init event as follows. The script below is wrapped in `<script>` tags in the in the MVC view that the controller returns and allows custom JS code for that particular view to be fired when the view has loaded.

```
 $('#pageCustomers').live('pageinit', function (event) {
    // do something
}
```